# execute powershell from SSMS

Tags: sql, json, powershell, api, ssms

I am trying to execute as certain xp_cmdshell code:

```
declare @url varchar(250) = 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02'
declare @c varchar(1000) = N'powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass '
  + N'-command (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '''+@url+'''-UseBasicParsing).content'
    print @c
exec xp_cmdshell @c
```

but this is the error that I get:

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
 
'appid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

when I try an execute the same thing in powershell I get the expected response(see image)

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02'-UseBasicParsing).content
```

[Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmLcv.png)

The expected output from the xp_cmdshell should be a json

Comment: Why do you *want* to execute it in SSMS in the first place?

Comment: I am trying to get API response into a table. I am not a C# developer, and i wanted to play around with sql server 2019 and json functionalities within ssms.

Comment: Then *push* the data to SQL Server. Calling web APIs isn't what SQL is designed to do. Use a different language to get the data to SQL Server, and then you can consume it inside SQL Server.

Comment: If you want to "play around" with JSON in SQL Server, then just get the JSON yourself and jimp the value into a variable to *play around* with. Don't cludge `xp_cmdshell` into it.

Comment: Side note, if you do paste your command into Command Prompt (which is what `xp_cmdshell` is using), [you get the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmDZy.png).

Comment: Thanks for the hints! 
What should be the best approach then? What language do i use to push the data?

Comment: What ever you like, if I am honest. You could use Powershell if you wanted by using `Invoke-Sqlcmd`. But we're moving away from what you've actually asked here; though the question we have is an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) at best.

Comment: My initial question was why this works in powershell, i mean just the Invoke-WebRequest part, What is in the brackets at the end of my question and  why in doesnt work in ssms

Comment: @vonPryz you are right. I have edited the question. I had an extra " ' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message implies that **your command line is being executed via `cmd.exe`, where `&` is a *metacharacter***.

To use `&` *verbatim* - as is your intent - *either* the URL of which `&` is a part must be enclosed in `"..."` (`cmd.exe` only recognizes *double* quotes) *or* you must **`^`-escape the `&`**:

```
declare @url varchar(250) = 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk^&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02'
-- ...
```

When `cmd.exe` parses the command line, it recognizes `^&` as an *escaped* `&` to be used verbatim, and removes `^`, the escape character, before passing the argument on.

Comment: The third opition is to use `-EncodedCommand` to pass the command in Base64, but that requires a few extra steps. No worries about escaping metacharacters, though.